# When Clicked on light, nodes go missing in node editor

Tags: light

When I click on light source to change its position, nodes go missing in node editor. Can anyone please tell me how to retain it back. 
Thanks

Comment: Did you try just selecting your object again?

Comment: maybe the nodes are not centered, try A to select all, then View > View Selected?

Comment: If the Node Editor has the "Use Nodes" Button visible click it else hover of the Node Editor and press the HOME key on your keyboard.